# Convert Textile to plain text

Tags: c#, plaintext, textile

How can I clean string with Textile markup to obtain plain-text? in C#?

For example, the string

```
Hello! How *do you do* ?
Y = 3 * X
```

..will be converted to:

```
Hello! How do you do ?
Y = 3 * X
```

I need to convert any Textile string, where I can found any markup of textile syntax ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language) ).
The char "*" is only one. There are also "**", "#", "*#", "_", "|", "h1.", "h2."... and so on.

I **temporarily solved the problem** converting Textile string to HTML, then HTML to Plain-Text. But it is bad bad **bad solution**.

Comment: how about the `Y = 3 * X`?

Comment: this is an example text. The first row use "*" to format string to  "strong"; and the second row use the same char in a math operation.

Comment: heres your guide `if (row %2) { } else { }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Textile.NET http://textilenet.codeplex.com/ which is a texttile formatter for .NET

Comment: Yes, I use it. But do you now how to use Textile.NET to convert Textile to plain-text?

Comment: Convert it to html then to text, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\*(.+)\*", @"$1")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I need to convert any Textile string, where I can found any markup of textile syntax ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language) ).
The char "*" is only one. There are also "**", "#", "*#", "_", "|", "h1.", "h2."... and so on.

I temporarily solved the problem converting Textile string to HTML, then HTML to Plain-Text. But it is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Im no real regex guru so someone can probably do this better. But..

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=[A-Za-z])\\*|\\*(?=[A-Za-z])", "");
```

This will replace any * preceeded by a-Z or any * followed by a-Z with ""